# How to store every 2 characters in c#

Tags: c#, store

Is there a way to store every 2 characters in a string?

e.g.

1+2-3-2-3+

So it would be "1+", "2-", "3-", "2-", "3+" as separate strings or in an array.

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: Please show code you've tried and have problem with.

Comment: Umm, loop through the string and move each substring copy to an array?  If this is your first introduction into C#, there are plenty of online resources and books.  I would start there.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way would be to walk your string with a loop, and take two-character substrings from the current position:

```
var res = new List<string>();
for (int i = 0 ; i < str.Length ; i += 2)
    res.Add(str.Substring(i, 2));
```

An advanced solution would do the same thing with LINQ, and avoid an explicit loop:

```
var res = Enumerable
    .Range(0, str.Length/2)
    .Select(i => str.Substring(2*i, 2))
    .ToList();
```

The second solution is somewhat more compact, but it is harder to understand, at least to someone not closely familiar with LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good problem for a regular expressio. You could try:

```
\d[+-]
```

Just find how to compile that regular expression ([HINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx)) and call a method that returns all occurrences.

Comment: +1. Dangerous (regular expressions can way to quickly become unreadable), but a least different approach.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop, and extract the characters using the [string.Substring()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) method, ensuring you do not go over the length of the string.

e.g.

```
string x = "1+2-3-2-3+";
const int LENGTH_OF_SPLIT = 2;
for(int i = 0; i < x.Length(); i += LENGTH_OF_SPLIT)
{
    string temp = null; // temporary storage, that will contain the characters

    // if index (i) + the length of the split is less than the
    // length of the string, then we will go out of bounds (i.e.
    // there is more characters to extract)
    if((LENGTH_OF_SPLIT + i) < x.Length())
    {
        temp = x.Substring(i, LENGTH_OF_SPLIT);
    }
    // otherwise, we'll break out of the loop
    // or just extract the rest of the string, or do something else
    else
    {
         // you can possibly just make temp equal to the rest of the characters
         // i.e.
         // temp = x.Substring(i);
         break; // break out of the loop, since we're over the length of the string
    }

    // use temp
    // e.g.
    // Print it out, or put it in a list
    // Console.WriteLine(temp);
}
```